# subsequences, real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(S_n)$ be a sequence. Assume that there is a sequence $(A_k)$ such that for every $k$, there is a subsequence of $(S_n)$ which converges to $A_k$. Assume further that $(A_k)$ converges to $a$. Show that there is a subsequence of $(S_n)$ which converges to $a$.

Can anyone help me with this question?

Answer (score 1):

With $k$ fixed, Let $(S_{n_j}^{(k)})$ be a subsequence that converges to $A_k$. Given $\epsilon >0,$ there exists $J_k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $j \geqslant J_k,$ then $|S_{n_j}^{(k)} - A_k| < \epsilon/2.$

Also, there exists $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $k \geqslant K$ then $|A_k - a| < \epsilon/2.$

Consider the subsequence $(S_{n_{J_k}}^{(k)})$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}.$  We have for every $k \geqslant 
K,$

$$|S_{n_{J_k}}^{(k)}-a| \leqslant |S_{n_{J_k}}^{(k)}-A_k| + |A_k - a| < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon.$$

Thus $S_{n_{J_k}}^{(k)} \to a.$

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for taking time editing and answering my question. Secondly, I want to learn how to type math symbols online. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @amundson: You're welcome. Start learning about MathJax at this link -- http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/148510

Comment: Thank you RRL. By the way, can you explain to me what this question is asking? They assume (A_k) and (S_n) approach to the same point?

Comment: No.  They assume that some sequence $(A_k)$ converges to $a.$  For every positive integer $k$ there is some subsequence of $(S_n)$ converging to $A_k.$  The sequence $(S_n)$ does not converge to $a$.  In fact, if the $A_k$ are not identically equal, then the sequence $(S_n)$ does not converge at all, since there are subsequences converging to different values. (If a sequence converges to a limit then every possible subsequence must converge to the same limit.)  However, they ask you to show there is yet another subsequence of $(S_n)$ that converges to $a.$

Answer (score 0):

For $k=1$, there is an index $n_1$ such that $|S_{n_1}-A_1|<1$.

For $k=2$, there is an index $n_2$ such that $n_2>n_1$ and  $|S_{n_2}-A_2|<\frac{1}{2}$.

For $k=3$, there is an index $n_3$ such that $n_3>n_2$ and  $|S_{n_3}-A_3|<\frac{1}{3}$.

Etc .....

Hence, we get a subsequence $(S_{n_k})$ such that

$$ |S_{n_k}-A_k|<\frac{1}{k}$$ for all $k$.

It follows that $S_{n_k}=S_{n_k}-A_k+A_k \to 0+a=a$   as $k \to \infty$.

FRED